# Fixtures with variable number of values depending on inputs

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to set up py.test such that fixture B can return a variable number of parameters given the value of fixture A. Let me illustrate with an example of the current implementation. For each of three objects, I would like to test a variable number of attributes.

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[Object1(), Object2(), Object3()])
def my_object(request):
    return request.param


def test_keys(my_object):
    for key in my_object.valid_keys:
        assert getattr(my_object, key) > 0, "mock test failed"
```

The above implementation is functional but it is not easy to see from the test output which of the `valid_keys` were tested. And if one of the tests fails, subsequent tests will not be executed. Ideally, I would like a setup as follows.

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[Object1(), Object2(), Object3()])
def my_object(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture
def valid_key(my_object):
    # Return each valid key separately for each input object


def test_keys(my_objects, valid_key):
    assert getattr(my_object, valid_key) > 0, "mock test failed"
```

This structure would allow me to analyse my tests more easily, observe coverage, ensure all tests are run independently etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there is exactly *the same number* of valid keys per object, then the code you wrote would be perfect. (exactly like yours for 1 valid key per object, and for more just add `params` to the second fixture).

If this is not enough, you must enter the big league and write a pytest hook named `pytest_generate_tests`, which lets you "define your own parametrization scheme" (according to the pytest docs)

Docs at: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the number of valid keys is variable.